# equivalence class and partially ordered sets question

Tags: elementary-set-theory

the question is -

1.we have 4 sets $A,B,C,D$ , if $AΔB⊆D$ and $BΔC⊆D$ then $AΔC⊆D$

2.given the power set $P$({1,2,3}) and given two relations $A,B∈$P$({1,2,3})$ $ARB$ if and only if $AΔB⊆$ {1,2} and $ASB$ if and only if AΔ{1,2}⊂BΔ{1,2}. which one of the sets is an equivalence relation ? prove it and find its classes

3. which one is a partially ordered set / total order set?

my tries:

i will start with the second part . ARB is the equivalence relation , because it is reflexive $AΔA⊆∅$ and $∅⊆${1,2} (not sure about this) . ARB is symmetric because $AΔB=BΔA$ and it is Transitive because if  $AΔB$ and $BΔZ$
then we can do ($AΔBΔBΔZ$)=$AΔZ$ as for equivalence classes what i got was ∅ , {1} , {2} and $N$/{1},{2} (im not sure about this one)

first part i didn't know how to do it but it feels like transitive relation but i could not figure out how to prove this  and for the third part anti reflexive is AΔ{1,2}⊂AΔ{1,2} should be AΔ{1,2}⊆AΔ{1,2}if it is reflexive transitive is the same as we did in the second part and we also need to check if it is comparable but i did not know how to how can i check if i can compare(not sure if it is the right word in English i searched but couldn't find)?

thanks for any help and explanation! and sorry if there are translation mistakes i will edit if there is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the relation $\mathcal{R}$, there are two equivalence classes here: the class of subsets that contain 3 and the class of subsets that don't contain 3. Indeed, $A\Delta B\subset\{1, 2\} \Longleftrightarrow 3\notin A\Delta B$. Note that an equivalence class is never empty. So, here the classes are
\begin{equation}
Cl_\emptyset =\{\emptyset, \{1\},\{2\}, \{1, 2\} \}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
Cl_{\{3\}} = \{\{3\}, \{1, 3\},\{2, 3\}, \{1, 2, 3\} \}
\end{equation}
For the relation $\mathcal{S}$, it is only a partial order because
\begin{equation}
\{1\}\Delta \{1, 2\} = \{2\}\quad \text{and} \quad \{1,2,3\}\Delta \{1, 2\} = \{3\}
\end{equation}
so that $\{1\}$ and $\{1, 2, 3\}$ are not comparable.